# Code block inside a list gets badly formated

Tags: latex, r-markdown, pandoc, quarto

Consider the following quarto document:

````
---
execute:
  cache: false
jupyter: python3
format: 
  pdf:
   number-sections: true
   fontsize: 12 pt
   papersize: A4
   fig-pos: 'H'
   geometry: "left=2.54cm,right=2.54cm,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm"
   classoption: abstract, table
   include-in-header:
     text: |
       \usepackage{fvextra}
       \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{breaklines,commandchars=\\\{\}}
       \usepackage[font=small]{caption}
       \usepackage{float}
       \usepackage{makecell}
       \usepackage{graphicx} 
       \geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=1cm,rmargin=1cm}
---
1. This is an item.

    a) Something

        ```{python}
         #|echo: false
         #|result: asis

         import pandas as pd

         data = {'A': [15, 30],
                'b': [8, 5]}

         df = pd.DataFrame(data)
         print(df)
        ```
````

The output is badly formatted, as can be seen below. Could someone please help me?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Pandoc docs](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#block-content-in-list-items),

> A list item may contain multiple paragraphs and other block-level content. However, subsequent paragraphs must be preceded by a blank line and indented to line up with the first non-space content after the list marker.

So if you want to indent both `a) Something` and Code output within the `1. This is an item.`, **you need to indent both of them so that they line up with the `T` character from `1. This is an item.`**.

````
---
[Used the Same YAML options as the OP. Removed them just to show the relevant part]
---

1. This is an item.

   a) Something
   
   ```{python}
   import pandas as pd
    
   data = {'A': [15, 30], 'b': [8, 5]}
    
   df = pd.DataFrame(data)
   print(df)
   ```
````

---

[image: code block inside the list]

---

And if you want to indent the code block within the second level list `a) Something`, **the code block must be indented to line up with the `S` character of `a) Something`.**

````
---
[Used the Same YAML options as the OP. Removed them just to show the relevant part]
---

1. This is an item.

   a) Something
   
      ```{python}
      import pandas as pd
    
      data = {'A': [15, 30], 'b': [8, 5]}
    
      df = pd.DataFrame(data)
      print(df)
      ```
````

---

[image: code block indented within the sublist]

---

**Also note the preceding blank line before the code chunk in both cases.**